# Python Overloading Operations

Tags: python-2.7, operator-overloading

I made a `Rational` class in python and made the `__add__`, `__mull__`, etc. operators for that class. Here is my code for the `__init__` and `__add__` functions:

```
class Rational(object):
        def __init__(self, p, q=None):  # p/q
            if q is None: q = 1
            if q == 0: raise ZeroDivisionError("division by zero!")
            self.p = p
            self.q = q
            self.simplify()  # simplify the fraction

        def __iadd__(self, other):  # +=
            self.p = self.p * other.q + self.q * other.p
            self.q = self.q * other.q
            self.simplify()
            return self

        def __add__(self, other):
            r = Rational(self.p, self.q)
            r += other
            return r
```

Now I would want python to understand things like `1 + Rational(1, 3)` (one plus a third). How could I implement this? Do I have to add an `__radd__` function and add cases to when `other` is int? Or is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this might be what you're looking for:

```
class Rational(object):
        def __init__(self, p, q=None):  # p/q
            if q is None: q = 1
            if q == 0: raise ZeroDivisionError("division by zero!")
            self.p = p
            self.q = q
            self.simplify()  # simplify the fraction

        def __iadd__(self, other):  # +=
            self.p = self.p * other.q + self.q * other.p
            self.q = self.q * other.q
            self.simplify()
            return self

        def __add__(self, other):
            if type(other) == int :
                r = Rational(self.p + other * self.q , self.q)
            else:
                r = Rational(self.p, self.q)
                r += other
            return r
```

This way you can define what happens when you add your Rational to another type, in this case you're adding an int so it relies on the following identity:

(p/q)+r=(p+qr)/q

I hope this helps!

EDIT: made a dumb mathematical error, fixed now